# Usage of "could" in "could account for as much as 7.0%"

Tags: meaning, modality

> “College Factual ranks Northwestern U as 46th out of a total 1,059
>   colleges and universities for sheer popularity with students from
>   China. **Chinese students could account for as much as 7.0% of the
>   entire student body** and as much as 41.1% of the international student
>   body at Northwestern U.”
>
> From
>   https://www.collegefactual.com/colleges/northwestern-university/student-life/international/

This text seems to be generated automatically instead of "written".

I originally asked a related question here. https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/could-account-for-as-much-as.3584373/#post-18238805 We have figured out the intended meaning of this sentence is **in 2017**, when the survey was taken, Chinese students accounted for 7.0% of the entire student body.  This is a fact.

How to understand "could" here? Is "could" here the past tense of "can"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "could" here means the same as 'might" it is not a past-tense form, rather it is expressing that this is possible, but uncertain. Probably in this case the data on which students are from China is incomplete or not fully reliable, so the text says that such students **could** account for seven percent -- or it might be somewhat less. Phrased this way the stated seven percent is implied to be the maximum plausible value. It could have been written as:

> Up to 7% of the student body might be from China.